# Hide Sidebar in Swift/Swiftui MacCatalyst 13.0+

Tags: ios, swift, mac-catalyst

I am looking for a way to hide my sidebar navigator on the left side of the screen.  This is all being done in Mac Catalyst and I would like it to work on Mac Catalyst 13.0+.  The views are presented as DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle with my home being the navigator and my first subview as the immediate view displayed.  So far I have not found anything on how to do this today as well.  I am using an NSToolbarDelegate, and a decider to see which layout to use.

Here is my ToolBar Code:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
let toolbarIdentifier = "com.example.apple-samplecode.toolbar"
let centerToolbarIdentifier = "com.example.apple-samplecode.centerToolbar"
let addToolbarIdentifier = "com.example.apple-samplecode.add"

extension SceneDelegate: NSToolbarDelegate {
    func toolbar(_ toolbar: NSToolbar, itemForItemIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSToolbarItem.Identifier, willBeInsertedIntoToolbar flag: Bool) -> NSToolbarItem? {

        if itemIdentifier == NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: toolbarIdentifier) {
            
            return NSToolbarItem(itemIdentifier: .toggleSidebar, barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "sidebar.left"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(toggleSideBar)))
        }
        
        return nil
    }
    
    @objc func toggleSideBar(sender: NSToolbarItem) {
        print("selection changed to index: \(sender)")
        
        
    }


    @objc func toolbarGroupSelectionChanged(sender: NSToolbarItemGroup) {
        print("selection changed to index: \(sender.selectedIndex)")
    }
    
    @objc func add(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("add clicked")
    }
    
    func toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        [NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: toolbarIdentifier), NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: centerToolbarIdentifier), NSToolbarItem.Identifier.flexibleSpace,
         NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: addToolbarIdentifier),
         NSToolbarItem.Identifier(rawValue: addToolbarIdentifier)]
    }
    
    func toolbarAllowedItemIdentifiers(_ toolbar: NSToolbar) -> [NSToolbarItem.Identifier] {
        self.toolbarDefaultItemIdentifiers(toolbar)
    }
}
#endif
```

And if this helps here is my deciders of how to display everything:

```
public func currentDeviceNavigationViewStyle() -> AnyView {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle()))
    #else
        return AnyView(self.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()))
    #endif
}
    
public func currentDisplayView() -> AnyView {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        return AnyView(macOSHomeView())
    #else
        return AnyView(Homeview())
    #endif
}
```

If you need anymore information please let me know because I have not done this part of Mac Catalyst yet, so I am always willing to expand on my question.